# Calculation of linear equation system

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I know that $$\frac{1}{x+2y+1 } +\frac{1}{2x+y-6 }=1$$

How can I calculate $x+y$?

Comment: Did you have any condition,like $x,y  \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: You tag system of equation, where is the second eq.?

Comment: Yes, x y z are positive numbers @Khosrotash

Comment: where is $z$  ?    , and did you mean $x,y>0 \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Wolfram tells me that $x=5, y=-2$ is a solution, which does indeed satisfy the equation. So we know what we're aiming for ! https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%282y%2Bx%2B1%29%2B1%5C%282x%2By-6%29%3D1

Comment: With $x=\frac{13}{3},y=-\frac{7}{6}$ given as another solution... Is something missing ?

Comment: Where is the system of linear equations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=1 ,a,b\in \mathbb{N} \to \frac12+\frac12=1 \to a=b=2$$so one of the solution come from $$\frac{1}{\underbrace{x+2y+1}_{2} } +\frac{1}{\underbrace{2x+y-6}_{2} }=1\\
\to \begin{cases}2x+y-6=2\\x+2y+1=2\end{cases}\to x=5,y=-2$$but you said $x,y,z >0$

Comment: Caution, we could have $b<0$.

Comment: Yes , you are right,but  B11b notice to positive solution .

Comment: you are right. the question is not clear yet!

Comment: Do you mean for example $a=\frac 12 , b=-1 $?

Comment: can you please make an example for $a,b$ with $b<0$  ? we were talking about $a,b$ didn't we  ?

Comment: Come on, $2\cdot1+1\cdot1-6=-3$.

Comment: I prefer to wait for B11b to clarify the question, It is a conversation without a result between us before clarifying question.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

$$\frac1a+\frac1b=1$$ can be written $$(a-1)(b-1)=1$$

and the only integer solutions are $a=b=0$ and $a=b=2$.

But as $x,y$ are positive, $x+2y+1>2$. There are no solutions.